# Model Passing Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have a UserDisplayModel with the default MembershipUser as a property, and I'm trying to pass the whole view model to the controller, but for some reason the MembershipUser property and likely the whole model gets lost.

I found this out because I get a `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` error unless I manually instantiate the MembershipUser inside the display model constructor). Meaning the second action (posted below) tried to make a new UserDisplayModel and errors because MembershipUser has no default constructor.

Here's my code:

Model

```
public class UserDisplayModel
{
    public MembershipUser User { get; set; }

    public UserDisplayModel(string id)
    {
        this.User = Membership.GetUser(id);
    }
}
```

Actions

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    UserDisplayModel model = new UserDisplayModel(id);

    return PartialView("Delete", model);
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(UserDisplayModel model)
{
    Membership.DeleteUser(model.User.UserName);
}
```

View

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcWebRole1.Models.UserDisplayModel>" %>

<p>Are you sure you want to delete the following user?</p>

<h2><%: Model.User.UserName%></h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <p>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User.UserName)%>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="small alert button" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="small secondary button cancel-action" />
    </p>
<% } %>
```

Is it possible to have this work, or does asp.net just not like having models inside models? Or did I just miss something silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Is caused by

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(UserDisplayModel model)
{
    Membership.DeleteUser(model.User.UserName);
}
```

As `UserDisplayModel` has no parameterless constructor for MVC to instantiate.  It only has the constructor:

```
public UserDisplayModel(string id)
{
    this.User = Membership.GetUser(id);
}
```

I would probably changed the method too look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(string userName)
{
    Membership.DeleteUser(userName);
}
```

Or to be a little more MVC

```
public class DeleteUserModel
{
    public DeleteUser User { get; set; }

    public class DeleteUser
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(DeleteUserModel model)
{
    Membership.DeleteUser(model.User.UserName);
}
```

Comment: Is there another solution? I want to be able to pass the whole model back in the form submit, for things like Edit actions.

Comment: My second solution (refresh I just posted it) would work.  For a delete you don't need the entire `UserDisplayModel`, just one that matches the signature of the submit.  It is *NOT* required for the model of a subsequent action to match the model used for the View.

Comment: Ah, that's great, I had no idea you could substitute models like that. Thanks!

Comment: If a property is not mappable, it simple won't be mapped.  That is the beauty of creating models for specific requests.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you really need here is the username.  So I would change the model to be

```
public class UserDisplayModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I just posted the relevant stuff, assume there is other data in the UserDisplayModel and I'm using all of the properties inside the MembershipUser object. I wanted to do this so that I could pass multiple models to the page view via the wrapper model (UserDisplayModel).